# SSLSocketImpl.java:595|SSLSocket duplex close failed. Debug info only. Exception details java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed

Tags: java, ssl, spring-webflux, spring-webclient, reactor-netty

In my application which is just a Spring Webflux Webclient, I am trying to send data to a third party server I have no control over, which has SSL enabled.

I am using this code to send requests to this server:

```
        WebClient client = WebClient.create().mutate().clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.create().keepAlive(true).secure(sslContextSpec -> sslContextSpec.sslContext(getMySSLContext())))).build();

final var response = client.post().uri("https://...")
```

Upon load (I am sending many requests to the server) I am always seeing this stack trace:

```
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|79|Keep-Alive-Timer|2023-05-15 11:05:39.124 CST|SSLSocketImpl.java:595|SSLSocket duplex close failed. Debug info only. Exception details: (
"throwable" : {
  java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.shutdownInput(Socket.java:1601)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.shutdownInput(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:217)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.shutdownInput(SSLSocketImpl.java:848)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.bruteForceCloseInput(SSLSocketImpl.java:798)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.duplexCloseOutput(SSLSocketImpl.java:660)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.close(SSLSocketImpl.java:584)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.closeServer(HttpClient.java:1137)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.KeepAliveCache.run(KeepAliveCache.java:260)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.InnocuousThread.run(InnocuousThread.java:162)}

)
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|C6|Keep-Alive-Timer|2023-05-15 10:08:48.053 UTC|null:-1|SSLSocket duplex close failed. Debug info only. Exception details: (
"throwable" : {
  java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.shutdownInput(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.shutdownInput(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.shutdownInput(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.bruteForceCloseInput(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.duplexCloseOutput(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.close(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.closeServer(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.closeServer(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.KeepAliveCache.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.InnocuousThread.run(Unknown Source)}

)
```

May I ask what does it mean?

Is it the third party server who is closing the socket? Or me the client?

if it is me, why am I closing the socket? I do have keepalive set to true. How to avoid me closing the socket?

What can I do in order to avoid this? What can I do to further debug this issue?